# Call to undefined function showfeeddialog() for FB.Connect.showFeedDialog

Tags: facebook

I am developing an Facebook application in `fb:iframe`. I do not want to use `feed_publishUserAction` as it requires a session key. Hence trying to use `FB.Connect.showFeedDialog`.

Is it OK to use the latter?

Can any one suggest example to use it as I am getting an error saying `Call to undefined function showfeeddialog()`.

Should I update my library?
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to make sure the client library is being included:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This should not be in the  of the HTML page but in the body. From the docs:

> *Note: You must include the `<script>` tag that loads the FeatureLoader at the 
>   beginning of your `<body>` element. The FeatureLoader may write body elements directly > to the document, which, if it happens within the `<head>` element, is reported as an 
>   error by some browsers.*

How are you calling the function? It should look something like:

```
FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(123456789, data);
```

(the numbers being the template id of the template you want to publish in, created in facebook or registered with the api. "data" should be the json you will populate said template with).

On thing to be aware of is that you need to make sure client library is ready to rock before you call any functions from it:

```
FB.ensureInit(function () { 
    // -- now library is officially ready
});
```

or check out the [`Waitable`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Waitable.waitUntilReady/) class.

Remember: you do have to have logged in via Facebook connect to use the `showFeedDialog` form. Also, having worked with the Connect API all week...it's still *very* beta and requires numerous workarounds. You should post some of your code so we can help further.